# How to satisfy Rayon's trait bounds in matrix multiplication algorithm?

Tags: rust, rayon

I implemented matrix multiplication using functional approach.

```rust
struct Matrix {
  vals: Vec<i32>,
  rows: usize,
  cols: usize,
}

fn mul(a: &Matrix, b: &Matrix) -> Matrix {
  assert_eq!(a.cols, b.rows);
  let vals = a
    .vals
    .par_chunks(a.cols)
    .map(|row| {
      (0..b.cols).map(|i| {
        row
          .iter()
          .zip(b.vals.iter().skip(i).step_by(b.cols))
          .map(|(a, b)| a * b)
          .sum()
      })
    })
    .flatten()
    .collect();
  Matrix {
    vals,
    rows: a.rows,
    cols: b.cols,
  }
}
```

I tried to parallelize this algorithm by using `par_chunks` from Rayon 1.8.1 instead of `chunks`, so each row is constructed in a separate thread. With `chunks` the algorithm works, but with `par_chunks` it results in two errors:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::iter::Map<std::ops::Range<usize>, {closure@src\main.rs:145:23: 145:26}>: rayon::iter::ParallelIterator` is not satisfied
   --> src\main.rs:153:6
    |
153 |     .flatten()
    |      ^^^^^^^ the trait `rayon::iter::ParallelIterator` is not implemented for `std::iter::Map<std::ops::Range<usize>, {closure@src\main.rs:145:23: 145:26}>`
```

and

```
error[E0599]: the method `collect` exists for struct `Flatten<Map<Chunks<'_, i32>, {closure@main.rs:144:10}>>`, but its 
trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src\main.rs:154:6
    |
141 |     let vals = a
    |  ______________-
142 | |     .vals
143 | |     .par_chunks(a.cols)
144 | |     .map(|row| {
...   |
153 | |     .flatten()
154 | |     .collect();
    | |     -^^^^^^^ method cannot be called due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    | |_____|
    | 
    |
   ::: C:\rust\.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib/rustlib/src/rust\library\core\src\iter\adapters\map.rs:62:1
    |
62  |   pub struct Map<I, F> {
    |   -------------------- doesn't satisfy `_: IntoParallelIterator`
    |
   ::: C:\rust\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\rayon-1.8.1\src\iter\flatten.rs:11:1
    |
11  |   pub struct Flatten<I: ParallelIterator> {
    |   ---------------------------------------
    |   |
    |   doesn't satisfy `_: Iterator`
    |   doesn't satisfy `_: ParallelIterator`
```

I have no idea what is going on. I suspect that it might be somehow related to sharing second matrix between threads but it is read-only and is guaranteed to stay in the scope until threads have finished their jobs. Error messages don't help at all. What am I doing wrong? How do I even read this error message?

UPD. Rayon's `prelude` is included.

Comment: It might be as simple as adding a missing trait. I usually go with `use rayon::prelude::*` which includes the necessary stuff for it to work

Comment: @LielFridman I have `use rayon::prelude::*;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages are not great here (the content is mostly correct but the location is misleading), but luckily there's only a few things that can go wrong when Rayon's trait bounds are not satisfied.

Here, [`flatten`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.flatten) expects to find items that implement [`ParallelIterator`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html). Instead, your `map` produces items which are a regular [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) type. You can fix this by inserting an [`into_par_iter`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.IntoParallelIterator.html#tymethod.into_par_iter):

```rust
.map(|row| {
    (0..b.cols).into_par_iter().map(|i| {
        row.iter()
            .zip(b.vals.iter().skip(i).step_by(b.cols))
            .map(|(a, b)| a * b)
            .sum()
    })
})
```

Rayon also has the [`flatten_iter`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.flatten_iter) method that is similar to `flatten` but works on regular `Iterator` types. This works well if the outer iterator already has enough items to occupy all your cores.

```rust
.map(|row| {
    (0..b.cols).map(|i| {
        row.iter()
            .zip(b.vals.iter().skip(i).step_by(b.cols))
            .map(|(a, b)| a * b)
            .sum()
    })
})
.flatten_iter()
```

And finally, there's [`flat_map_iter`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.flat_map_iter), which just combines `map` and `flatten_iter` into one function.

```rust
.flat_map_iter(|row| {
    (0..b.cols).map(|i| {
        row.iter()
            .zip(b.vals.iter().skip(i).step_by(b.cols))
            .map(|(a, b)| a * b)
            .sum()
    })
})
// no .flatten()
```

Comment: I tried all 3 fixes and all of them work. But how did you figure out where to look at? How do you find it in general? Error messages are barely helpful in this case. Is it experience or is there some kind of "The Rayon Book"?

Comment: @SunofAbeach Just experience. I spent lots of time trying to figure this out in my own code in the past.